# How to delete a post in Nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

I try to delete a post in NHibernate but nothing happens. Updating, selecting and inserting new items works fine but when I try to delete nothing happens.

```
  IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("from Color where name like '%" + TextBox2.Text.Trim() + "%'");
        Color color = query.List<Color>()[0];
        session.Delete(color);
```

**Edit:** 
I forgot to call the flush method. Now works fine. Like this:

```
session.Flush();
```

Comment: you can add `session.Flush()` as an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> session.Flush();